# JS fade in not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I have searched for about 2 hours now and I just can't get a hold of this.

I am using bootstrap and I want to have three columns with "col-xs-6" placed next to each other. However, when I click the button, I want the outer column that is visible to collapse in and the column on the other side to show up. The blue column in the middle should not change at all, just the visibility of the outer columns. 
I know I could just use `display: none` but this would not look as smooth as a CSS3 Transition.

The fade Out works perfectly fine, but instead of fading in, the div will just be at 50% width right after the display property has set.

Here is a fiddle:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zekr3af3/3/)

And here is the Code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 red fadeIn">
      Hello i am the red div
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 blue">
      Hello i am the blue div
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 green fadeOut is-out">
      Hello i am the green div
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>&nbsp;TOGGLE
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    var eleForFadeIn;
  var eleForFadeOut;
    if ($('.green').hasClass('is-out')){
    eleForFadeIn = $('.green');
    eleForFadeOut = $('.red');
  }
  else {
    eleForFadeIn = $('.red');
    eleForFadeOut = $('.green');
  }
  eleForFadeIn.addClass('fadeIn');
  eleForFadeIn.removeClass('fadeOut');
  eleForFadeOut.addClass('fadeOut');
  eleForFadeOut.removeClass('fadeIn');

  setTimeout(function() { doFadeIn(eleForFadeIn); }, 150);
  setTimeout(function() { doFadeOut(eleForFadeOut); }, 1500);
});

function doFadeIn(element){
  element.removeClass('is-out');
}
function doFadeOut(element){
    element.addClass('is-out');
}
```

CSS:

```
.red{
  background-color: red;
  height: 250px;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s;
  transition: width 2s;
}
.blue{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 250px;
}
.green{
  background-color: green;
  height: 250px;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s;
  transition: width 2s;
}
.fadeOut{
  width: 0px;
}
.fadeIn{
  width: 50%;
}

.is-out{
  display: none;
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

**Edit**: The timeout functions are used because i want the display property to be none at the end of the transition. Yes i tried to build in the transition eventlistener but it did not work... So if you know how to implement int i would appreciate any suggestions :-)

**Edit2**: Trying to express myself a bit more cleary about my goals.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: If you're using timeouts, then why bother using css transitions, why not just use jquery for the effect? (perhaps I'm naive)

Comment: 6+6+6=18, not 12.  bootstrap is always 12 columns (one of the reasons I dislike it for layout so much... but that's just preference)

Comment: i dont realy want 3 columns next to each other, i think i did not make that clear enough. i want one of the columns to be completely gone! 

I would like to only use JQuery for trigging stuff. I want to use CC3 whenever i can because i think it is a bit smoother.

Thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

display:none can't really be animated and that is where your problem lies. Change it to this and all should be well.

```
.is-out {
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSFiddle you show doesn't produce three adjacent columns. Regardless, the reason the column takes up 50% of the width after the fade out is because it has the class `col-xs-6`. This class uses Bootstrap's grid system to size the element to 6/12 == 1/2 the available horizontal space.

If you want three adjacent columns, I suggest using `col-xs-4` since 12/3 == 4. After fading out the outer two columns. You should adjust the class of the remaining one to be `col-xs-12` instead of `col-xs-4` so it will take up the entire horizontal width.

Comment: Hello Hexturtle, 
i think i didn't write what i want in a clear enough way. I will Edit my Question so my goals will become a bit more obvious.